# JAXB and multiple content types within the same element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

In JAXB, is it possible to define the following case:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="param1">value1</param>
    <parameter name="someCollection">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="param2">value2</param>
            <parameter name="param3">value3</param>
        </parameters>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

where a `parameter` element can sometimes have a simple value ("value1") and sometimes it can have other elements (such as another `parameters` element).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlPath` extension in [EclpseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), I'm the MOXy text lead.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

The `@XmlPath` extension will enable you to map the following class:

```
package blog.predicate;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="node")
@XmlType(propOrder={"firstName", "lastName", "address", "phoneNumbers"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlPath("node[@name='first-name']/text()")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlPath("node[@name='last-name']/text()")
    private String lastName;

    @XmlPath("node[@name='address']")
    private Address address;

    @XmlPath("node[@name='phone-number']")
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

}
```

To an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
   <node name="first-name">Jane</node>
   <node name="last-name">Doe</node>
   <node name="address">
      <node name="street">123 A Street</node>
   </node>
   <node name="phone-number" type="work">555-1111</node>
   <node name="phone-number" type="cell">555-2222</node>
</node>
```